# Background size gradients using highcharts

Tags: css, angular, svg, highcharts, linear-gradients

I am using highcharts with an angular component, along with that I am making a column chart using the following data.

```js
  accessGroupUsageData: AnalyticsStatus[] = [
    { y: 430, name: 'Public', percent: Math.round((430 / 4185) * 100) }, 
    { y: 430, name: 'Executivers', percent: Math.round((430 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 400, name: 'Convention Grounds', percent: Math.round((400 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 400, name: 'Group 4', percent: Math.round((400 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 400, name: 'Group 5', percent: Math.round((400 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 350, name: 'Group 6', percent: Math.round((350 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 350, name: 'Group 7', percent: Math.round((350 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 300, name: 'Group 8', percent: Math.round((300 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 250, name: 'Group 9', percent: Math.round((250 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 250, name: 'Group 10', percent: Math.round((250 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 225, name: 'Group 11', percent: Math.round((225 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 200, name: 'Group 12', percent: Math.round((200 / 4185) * 100) },
    { y: 200, name: 'Group 13', percent: Math.round((200 / 4185) * 100) }
  ]
// here are the colors
  gradientColors = {
    purple: 'var(--analytics-gradient-purple, #ffffff)', //#9379F9
    blue: 'var(--analytics-gradient-blue, #ffffff)', // #56A5FB
    lightblue: 'var(--analytics-gradient-lightblue, #ffffff)' // #35BDDC
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve
accesssGroupUsageData[0] to be purple to the light blue,
repeating down for each column to be reduced in the purple color that is above 50%. Below 50% height along with anything below 50% heigh to go from blue to light blue.

First try that resulted in all columns going from purple to light blue.

```js
series: [
        {
          name: undefined,
          legendSymbol: undefined,
          color: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
              [0, this.gradientColors.purple], // start 
              [0.5, this.gradientColors.blue], // middle
              [1, this.gradientColors.lightblue] // end
            ],

          },
          type: 'column',
          borderRadius: 0,
          borderWidth: 0,
          zIndex: 3,
          stickyTracking: false,
          tooltip: {
            followPointer: false,
          },
          data: this.chartDataSource
        }
      ]
```

Second try that resulted in all columns being light blue (and manually changing to percent calculate * 100 still left the color as light blue) using the following function:

```js
calculateGradientStops(data: number[]): Highcharts.GradientColorObject {
    const max = Math.max(...data);
    const stops: Highcharts.GradientColorStopObject[] = [];

    data.forEach(value => {
      const percent = value / max;
      if (percent <= .5) {
        stops.push([percent, this.gradientColors.purple]);
      } else {
        stops.push([percent, this.gradientColors.blue]);
      }
    });

    console.log(stops)

    return {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
      stops: stops
    }
  }
```

As well as the above I was looking at using styledMode=true but that results in a bit more refactor than am able to do at the moment.

Links:
This is what it currently does - https://imgur.com/a/GOtFOKC
This is what I want to achieve - https://imgur.com/a/CkDIdte

Comment: I don't quite understand what the effect is supposed to be. Are you able to represent this in an image? It would also be nice if you could do an online demo, it would be easier to help 

Comment: Hi @Michał, I will work on getting a jsFiddle up, but in the mean time here are some imgur links.   
this is what it currently does: https://imgur.com/a/bDDJgOt   
this is what I want to achieve: https://imgur.com/a/awmRIr6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to achieve something like this?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    color: {
      linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
      stops: [
        [0, 'red'],
        [0.5, 'orange'],
        [1, 'green']
      ]
    },
    data: [2, 5, 9, 3, 6, 5]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4hbxn38v/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GradientColorObject

Comment: Thanks, @Michał! That is what I was going for yes, for my own understanding though, how did you find out about this line?
```typescript
linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
```

I did not see it when I was looking over the docs and I did not see it in the docs you linked as well. When I looked over the LinearGradientColorObject all I saw was {x0, y0, x1, y1}?

Comment: You are right, it is not documented and properly typed. I've seen this solution before, that's why I sent it. From what I have tested now, this array does not correspond to the coordinates from the object. Additionally, while checking what can be given in this variable, I found another interesting case where the gradient can be set horizontally, common to all points: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7jvnh6qx/